# I need to run an operator after variables have been restored

Tags: python

I need to run an operator once an addon has been registered but at them moment if I do anything with "foo_number" it is at default rather than the saved version of it:

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "foo",
    "author": "",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 79, 0),
    "description": "",
    "category": "3D View"}

import bpy
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent


class foo_variables(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    foo_number = bpy.props.IntProperty(
        name = "foo",
        default = 1
    )


class foo_update(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "foo.foo_update"
    bl_label = "foo"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER'}

    def execute(self, context):
        print("some operation")
        # do something with foo number

        return {'FINISHED'}


@persistent
def update_op(scene):
    bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_pre.remove(update_op)
    bpy.ops.foo.foo_update()


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(foo_update)
    bpy.utils.register_class(foo_variables)
    bpy.types.Scene.foo_vars = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type = foo_variables)
    bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_pre.append(update_op)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(foo_update)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(foo_variables)
    del bpy.types.Scene.foo_variables
```

I now have this, but I cant find a way to remove the handler without it breaking:

```
@persistent
def update_op(scene):
    # bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_pre.remove(update_op)
    bpy.ops.foo.foo_update()


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(foo_update)
    bpy.utils.register_class(foo_variables)
    bpy.types.Scene.foo_vars = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type = foo_variables)
    bpy.app.handlers.load_post.append(update_prefix)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(foo_update)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(foo_variables)
    del bpy.types.Scene.foo_variables

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Personally wouldn't mix handlers and operators like this. Why not do something directly with `scene.foo_variables` in the handler.  Also how are you re registering this to test? If unregister is called it will clear the variable.

Comment: I was just using an operator to test it was working in the right order, I have managed to get it working as I want, by registering bpy.app.handlers.load_post.append(update_prefix) and removing the handler.remove from the function, but now the problem is I am not removing the handler so it is still running? I added the new code to the post

Comment: Actually bpy.app.handlers.load_post only runs after a file is loaded, So I could probably just leave it like this without it doing any unnecessary loops? It will only run update_op if a new file is loaded?